# Unable to open PNG file with kview or PictureViewer; opens fine with other viewers

Tags: png, libpng

I have a PNG file created using libPNG library. The file opens perfectly on Windows picture viewer and MS Paint, but opening with kview (on Linux RHEL5) or QuickTime PictureViewer (on Windows) fails - the former reports a "libpng read error whereas the latter reports the file as being corrupted. A similar problem is seen when trying to process the PNG using ImageMagick library on Linux. Given that the PNG opens fine on some applications, it doesn't seem that the file is really corrupted; I therefore suspect some problem with version compatibility, but I am not sure. I tried searching the web but couldn't find any information on the root cause or a solution to this problem. Can someone please guide me on this?

Comment: Try this: http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't have the option of modifying the PNG files manually using such tools; instead, I would like to identify what is causing the problem on some of the viewers and modify my code to circumvent the problem.

By the way, I did try out inspecting the problematic PNG files using tweakpng tool. The inspection view didn't report any error but the "image viewer" of the tool wasn't able to display the file - it reported an "unexpected end of file" error. Any pointers on the root cause and ways to fix it would be very helpful.

Comment: It's hard to say without more info, it would seem to be some buggy/non-standard zlib encoding in the IDAT chunkds. Can't you post an example image?

Comment: @leonbloy Sorry, missed replying earlier. Here is one such PNG: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2WM9H.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the  example image you posted in the comments, the problem is that your PNG lacks  the ending IEND chunk -something you can test by opening it with [tweakpng](http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/) and inspecting the structure visually, or choosing "Check Validity-F5". It is somewhat predictable that those kind of PNG are displayed by some viewers and rejected by others.

If you are using libpng, it seems you forgot to call `png_write_end()`

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem! It turned out that I was indeed not calling `png_write_end()`; after modifying my code to call that method, the created PNG files are opening on kview.